# How can I change precision in timer in std::chrono? It starts at value 1000

Tags: c++, timer, std, c++-chrono

I made a timer class using std::chrono. I want to measure time of some process in code. The problem is that this process is really fast (less than 1000 nanoseconds) but timer starts counting values at 1000. If it is less than 1000 it changes to 0. Then my output is "0 Nanoseconds" and i want to get e.g "50 Nano seconds". Is there any solution for my problem?

```
class Timer {
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start_time;
     std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> stop_time;

  public:
    void start()
    {
        start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        stop_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    void print_time_duration()
    {
        std::cout<<"This Function took: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop_time - start_time).count()<<" Nanoseconds."<<std::endl;
    }
    int return_time_duration()
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop_time - start_time).count();
    }

};
```

And then...

```
Timer time;
time.start();
// DO SOMETHING HERE
time.stop();
time.print_time_duration();
```

Comment: _Class std::chrono::high_resolution_clock represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation._ You can't get more precise

Comment: If your function is less than 1000 nanoseconds, then why bother timing it? Probably takes longer to set up the timer :/

Comment: You could try to come up with a more precise clock and write your own compatible `clock` class. You'll need some specialized hardware.

Comment: Try running your function a large number of times, measuring only the total time and figuring out the average run time instead.

Comment: Yeah.. I'll have to measure average time then. Thanks for your advices :)